# Can not upload updated apk on play store

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-play

When I want to upload my updated app version the roll out button is disabled. 
There is alert in app release part of google play console that says you can't edit this app until you create a new app release declaring sensitive permissions. 
In my 1.6 version app there is auto read message permission and I want to upload 1.7 version removing the permission. How can I solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's accute problem. Seems that there is no single solution. Different people handle this problem in different ways.

Take a look at this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ajddj6/play_store_console_you_cant_edit_this_app_until/)

In my case I tried to delete releases from test track (alpha, beta, internal, closed) with SMS permissions. But I only succeed for alfa. After that I few times tried to move Internal test track to alpha. I thought to delete release from alpha after moving it. Unexpectedly permission form appeared. I filled the form and sent it. The error dessapeared after this. I create new releases for test and prod tracks and now everything is OK